# Construct a 4th-order tensor with matricization ranks $r$ that is not rank $r$

Tags: tensor

I ask you for this *possibly not so simple* task:

- **Explicitly** construct a 4th-order tensor $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n_1 \times \ldots \times n_4}$ that **does not** have (border) rank $r$, but for which each matricization **does** have rank $r$; that is
  $$\forall J \subset \{1,\ldots,4\},\ |J| \notin \{0,4\}\ :\ r_J := \mathrm{rank}(A^{[J]}) = r,$$
  where each $A^{[J]} \in \mathbb{C}^{n_J \times n_{\{1,\ldots,4\} \setminus J}}$ for $n_S := \prod_{s \in S} n_s$ is a simple reshaping into a matrix *(see below)*.

For simplicity, let $n_j = \hat{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $j = 1,\ldots,4$.

You may choose $\hat{n},r \in \mathbb{N}$ as you wish. Convincing numerical evidence is welcome as well.

---

*The following Matlab code displays all relevant matricization ranks:*

```
n = size(A);
r_1 = rank( reshape(A,n(1),[]) )
r_2 = rank( reshape(A,n(2),[]) )
r_3 = rank( reshape(A,n(3),[]) )
r_4 = rank( reshape(A,n(4),[]) )
r_12 = rank( reshape(A,n(1)*n(2),[]) )
r_13 = rank( reshape( permute(A,[1,3,2,4]) ,n(1)*n(3),[]) )
r_14 = rank( reshape( permute(A,[1,4,2,3]) ,n(1)*n(4),[]) )
```

*Note that $\mathrm{rank}(A^{[J]}) = \mathrm{rank}((A^{[J]})^T) = \mathrm{rank}(A^{[\{1,\ldots,d\} \setminus J]})$.*

Comment: Do you really need every matricization to have the exact same rank? Or would it suffice to give a tensor with each matricization having rank $\leq r$, while the tensor itself has rank $> r$?

Comment: I suppose that would be fine. However, I would expect this to ultimately be a harder problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall papers giving lower bounds on border rank for tensors with more than 3 factors, but we can adapt the constructions from the trilinear case.

If we want an order $4$ tensor with all flattening ranks the same, one way is to take a commutative algebra $R$ and take $A$ to be the tensor corresponding to the iterated multiplication map $A \colon R \times R \times R \to R$ defined as $A(x,y,z) = x\cdot y\cdot z$.
If $\dim R = r$, this $r \times r \times r \times r$ tensor will have all flattening ranks also equal to $r$ (you can see this by grouping products in a nice way, for example, the identity $A(x, y, z) = \sum_{i = 1}^r e^i(x\cdot y) (e_i \cdot z)$ will give a rank $r$ decomposition for the $12|34$ flattening rank).

One can argue like in our paper with Markus Bläser ["On degeneration of tensors and algebras"](https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.MFCS.2016.19) and prove that the border rank of such iterated multiplication tensor will be equal to $r$ if and only if the algebra $R$ is smoothable. The simplest non-smoothable algebra is 8-dimensional $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/\left(x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^2,x_3^2,x_3x_4,x_4^2,x_1x_4-x_2x_3\right)$ (taken from [this paper of Poonen](https://doi.org/10.4171/jems/131)) which gives the tensor
$$\begin{aligned}
A & = e^{\otimes 4} \\
& + \sum_{i = 1}^4 (x_i \otimes e \otimes e \otimes x_i + e \otimes x_i \otimes e \otimes x_i + e \otimes e \otimes x_i \otimes x_i)\\
& + \sum_{i = 1}^3 (y_i \otimes e \otimes e \otimes y_i + e \otimes y_i \otimes e \otimes y_i + e \otimes e \otimes y_i \otimes y_i)\\
& + x_1 \circ x_3 \circ e \otimes y_1 + x_1 \circ x_4 \circ e \otimes y_2\\
& + x_2 \circ x_3 \circ e \otimes y_2 + x_2 \circ x_4 \circ e \otimes y_3\\
\end{aligned}$$
in $\textrm{span}(e, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, y_1, y_2, y_3)^{\otimes 4}$, where $a \circ b \circ c$ is the symmetrized product $a \circ b \circ c = a \otimes b \otimes c + a \otimes c \otimes b + b \otimes c \otimes a + b \otimes a \otimes c + c \otimes a \otimes b + c \otimes b \otimes a$.

The modification proposed by Nathaniel Johnston in the comments is actually easier, as we can just take an order 3 tensor $T$ which has the same property and take $A = v \otimes T$ where $v$ is an arbitrary vector. The flattening ranks would be either $1$ or the same as $T$, and the border rank the same as $T$.

Comment: Am I counting correctly, the expression for $A$ shows the rank is at most 46? Do you know the exact value of the rank of this $A$, or tensors like it (multiplication maps)?

Comment: I know a lower bound (d - 1)(n - 1) + 1 for similar iterated tensors of order d and size n, it's in our paper arXiv:2211.00652.

Comment: For this specific tensor I see an upper bound of 38, because the rank of $a \circ b \circ c$ is $4$